# When I map over a populated array in this.state, why does it return undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

In my app I have a home component that is rendered after a user logins. In this home component's componentDidMount I fetch the documents associated with the logged in user. The fetch call works and the response is populated with the correct data. I take this data and make a this.setState call, setting the fetched data to this.state.

In the home components render function I insert JSX that calls a function to map over this.state.docs and display that data. Even though the data in this.state can be logged successfully in the Home component's render function, the result of mapping over the data always returns undefined.

If i create a new document it does get inserted and displays correctly, but the older documents never display.

Here's my home component:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const axiosConfig = {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      docs: [],
      username: '',
      userid: '',
      newDocumentName: '',
      newDocumentPassword: '',
      loading: true
    };
    console.log('this.props in home constructor ', this.props);
  }

  newDoc() {
    console.log('this.state before new doc ', this.state);
    axios(localStorage.getItem('url') + '/newDoc', {
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        title: this.state.newDocumentName,
        password: this.state.newDocumentPassword
      },
      withCredentials: true
    }).then(resp => {
      console.log('the response to new doc ', resp);
      this.setState({
        docs: [...this.state.docs, resp.data.document],
        newDocumentName: '',
        newDocumentPassword: ''
      });
    });
  }

  renderDocumentList() {
    return this.state.docs.map((doc, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <Link to={`/editDocument/${doc._id}`}>{doc.title}</Link>
      </div>
    ));
  }

  logout() {
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:3000/logout')
      .then(resp => {
        this.props.history.replace('/');
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      let resp = await axios
        .get(
          localStorage.getItem('url') +
            '/getAllDocs/' +
            this.props.match.params.userid,
          axiosConfig
        )
        .then(resp => {
          console.log('awaited response in comp did mount of home ', resp);
          this.setState({
            docs: [resp.data.docs],
            username: resp.data.username,
            userid: resp.data.userid,
            loading: false
          });
        });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Loading...</h2>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="page-container">
          <div className="document-header">
            <button className="logout-button" onClick={() => this.logout()}>
              Logout
            </button>
            <h3>Welcome, {this.state.username}.</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="create-or-share-document-div">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="New document name"
              name="newDocumentName"
              value={this.state.newDocumentName || ''}
              onChange={event => {
                this.setState({ newDocumentName: event.target.value });
              }}
              style={{ width: '30%' }}
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="new document password"
              name="newDocumentPassword"
              value={this.state.newDocumentPassword || ''}
              onChange={event => {
                this.setState({ newDocumentPassword: event.target.value });
              }}
              style={{ width: '30%' }}
            />
            <button
              style={{
                border: 'solid black 1px',
                padding: '5px',
                borderRadius: '10px',
                height: '3%',
                backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
              }}
              onClick={() => this.newDoc()}
            >
              Create Document
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="document-container">
            <div className="document-list">
              <p>My Documents:</p>
              <ul>{this.renderDocumentList()}</ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="create-or-share-document-div">
            <input
              style={{ width: '30%' }}
              type="text"
              placeholder="paste a docID to collab on a doc"
              ref="sharedDoc"
            />
            <button
              style={{
                border: 'solid black 1px',
                padding: '5px',
                borderRadius: '10px',
                height: '3%',
                backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
              }}
            >
              Add Shared Doc
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Are you sure it should be `docs: [resp.data.docs]` and not `docs: resp.data.docs`? It might be that you create an array inside an array.

Comment: Thanks, Tholle. That fixed the problem. I'm not sure why but there is no check mark next to your answer to vote correct but 100% this fixed my issue.

Comment: Awesome! I added an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the `docs` in state to `[resp.data.docs]`, which is an array inside of an array. Use the `resp.data.docs` array directly instead:

```
this.setState({
  docs: resp.data.docs,
  username: resp.data.username,
  userid: resp.data.userid,
  loading: false
});
```